# Two objects that looked like stars?

Tags: observational-astronomy

My husband and I were on the back porch looking at the stars, and two caught my eye when I noticed they were moving away from us in a zigzag pattern we watched until we couldn’t see them anymore. The speed was much faster than a plane and there were no blinking lights on them. Every other plane in the sky was clearly a plane. What could this have been?

Comment: Anything moving in a zig zag pattern won't be related to astronomy, so you might be better off asking in a different forum.

Comment: sounds like a drone/quadcopter